# Why a Scanner cannot be reused?

Tags: java, java.util.scanner, java-io

I created a method called `readFileAsScanner`. It creates a file and a `Scanner` which attaches to the file. Then returns the `Scanner`.

Neverthelesss, I use it. The `Scanner` can be only used once. Why? Can I reset it by the `reset()` method of `Scanner` to make it reusable?

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;
public class Lab10{
    public static void main(String[] args)throws FileNotFoundException{
        String[] words = readWords();
        int i;
        for(i=0;i<words.length;i++)
            System.out.println(words[i]);
        System.out.println(words.length);
    }

    public static String[] readWords()throws FileNotFoundException{
        Scanner data = readFileAsScanner();
        String[] words = new String[estimateWords(data)];   
        int i=0;
        while(data.hasNext()){
            System.out.println(data.next());    
        }   
        return words;
    }
    public static Scanner readFileAsScanner() throws FileNotFoundException{
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Input file name:");
        //String fileName = input.next();
        String fileName = "unsorted.txt";
        Scanner data = new Scanner(new File(fileName)); 
        return data;    
    }
    public static int estimateWords(Scanner data){
        int estimatedSize = 0;
        while(data.hasNext()){
            data.next();    
            estimatedSize++;    
        }
        return estimatedSize;
    }

}
```

Comment: Your Scanner seems to be attached to `System.in`; not a File.

Comment: I have two Scanners. The second one is the one I am asking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're consuming everything that you want to read in the `estimateWords` method call.  By the time the scanner advances to the end of the file, you've read pretty much everything there is to read in the file, and the scanner's next call to `hasNext()` will return false.

You can fix this in one of two ways:

- Open the file twice with a `Scanner` instance in each method call and pass in the filename, or
- Open the file once, perform both a count and a reading of data in one method only.

I would opt for the latter, since it would be more straightforward and better practice (you typically don't see `Scanner` instances passed around).

Comment: There is no method to reset the Scanner from the beginning?

Comment: No.  Don't let `reset()` fool you; it doesn't reset the position of the `Scanner`'s last read spot.

Answer (score 0):

Because the underlying stream is at end, and probably cannot be rewound or reset, and you can't attach a existing Scanner to another stream.